# How do I reference a namespace in another .cs file?

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2013

So I'm for one of my own .cs files, I'm trying to use the TestPDF Namespace from the last post here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1886131.aspx?Convert+HTML+to+PDF+using+iTextSharp

which is contained within HTMLToPDFBuilder.cs. So for my someFile.cs I try to use the TestPDF namespace with `using TestPDF;` However, it says

> The type/namespace could not be found [...]

How do I add a directive/assembly reference to this namespace within the file? I'm using VS2013 and tried right clicking my project stub in the solution and did Add>Reference, but it only takes .dll-esque file extensions, not .cs ones.

Comment: I think you can just import the .cs file into your project by right clicking it and then Add Existing Item.

Comment: Add the .cs file to your project.

Comment: That did it Savanna King. Feel free to make that an answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click and then 'Add Existing Item'. Answer courtesy of @Savanna King.

Answer (score 0):

Add your DLL to your references library, if you still get this error then CLEAN your solution then REBUILD.